# Fixing a nullpointerexception in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array being written to a file from another method. I've defined the contents of the 2d array in my sightings method, but when it passes over to the save method the contents (in at least block [1] [1]) become null. How do I go about making sure the value remains defined?
My code so far:

(Sightings Method)

```
public void Sighting()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String MigChoice; //initiates Migrant Choice variable to be stored
    String Trail; //initiates Trail to be stored
    String NumberSeen; //initiates number to be stored
    String Species; //initiates species to be stored
    String Date; //initiates date to be stored
    String[][] EntryList;
    EntryList = new String [500][5];
    System.out.print("What species of bird was observed?\n");
    Species = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What trail did this spotting take place on?\nDirectory:\n");
    System.out.println("1). Alligator Alley");
    System.out.println("2). Eagle Roost");
    System.out.println("3). Heron Hideout");
    System.out.println("4). Lost Bridge Trail");
    System.out.println("5). Marsh Rabbit Run");
    System.out.println("6). Otter");
    System.out.println("7). Shady Oak");
    System.out.println("8). Wading Bird Way");
    System.out.println("9). Windmill Whisper");
    Trail = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The species is:\n1.)Migrant\n2.)Residential");
    System.out.print("Please enter Migrant or Residential: ");
    MigChoice = input.next();
    System.out.print("What was the time of this sighting (in mm/dd/yyyy format)?\n");
    Date = input.next();
    System.out.print("Finally, how many birds were observed?\n");
    NumberSeen = input.next();
    EntryList [0][0] = Species;
    EntryList [0][1] = Trail;
    EntryList [0][2] = MigChoice;
    EntryList [0][3] = Date;
    EntryList [0][4] = NumberSeen;
    Save(EntryList);
    System.out.print("Thank you for adding an entry!");
    System.out.println("Returning to main menu");
    Menu();
 }
```

(Save Method)

```
  public void Save(String[][] EntryList) {
    try {
        String[][] content = EntryList;
        File file = new File("CBB.dat");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        if (EntryList[0][0] != null) {
            DataInputStream instream;
            DataOutputStream outstream;
            instream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(file))); // buffers the data stream
            outstream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file)));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("CBB.dat", true);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for (int row = 0; row < EntryList.length; row++) {
                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][0]);

                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][1]);

                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][2]);

                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][3]);

                outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][4]);
            }
            outstream.close();
        } else
            System.out.print("Something is wrong");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:330)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:306)
at Dossier.Save(Dossier.java:158)
at Dossier.Sighting(Dossier.java:133)
```

Comment: You're only set  `EntryList [0][0]`, `EntryList [0][1]`, `EntryList [0][2]`, `EntryList [0][3]`, and `EntryList [0][4]`, so `EntryList[1][1]` will be null

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that mistake, but the error still occurs when I've set the if(EntryList[1][1] != null) to if(EntryList[0][0] != null). Any more insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the error message and stacktrace in your question?

Comment: The error message has been added.

Comment: I just answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) will be throw `NullPointerException` if you pass a null object as parameter.

> Writes two bytes of length information to the output stream, followed
>   by the modified UTF-8 representation of every character in the string
>   s. If s is null, a NullPointerException is thrown. Each character in
>   the string s is converted to a group of one, two, or three bytes,
>   depending on the value of the character.

You can add null check if your loop:

```
  for (int row = 0; row < EntryList.length; row++)
  {
          for(int col = 0; col < EntryList[row].length;col++) {
               if(EntryList[row][col] != null)
                  outstream.writeUTF(EntryList[row][col]); 
          } 
  }
```

Comment: Why 5 condition when you can do an another for and fix it with only one?

Comment: That definitely helps. One more thing, the program doesn't seem to append the text file, though I have the line  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("CBB.dat", true);. Would you happen to know why this is?

Comment: @Sam: yeah, I just made it more simpler...Thanks!

Comment: Ah, actually that edit fixed the problem. Thanks for all your help!